# Calc I limit/series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, induction

Let $f : \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function that is differentiable at zero and such that $f(0)=0$. Show that for each $n\in \mathbb N$ we have that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\left(f(x)+f(\frac{x}{2})+...+f(\frac{x}{n})\right)=\left(1+\frac12+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)f'(0)$$

me: i believe that $f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ but i still don't understand how to go about this question, any help is appreciated !

Comment: The equality about f' you wrote is srrictly true for limot as x approaches 0 (limit definitipn)the part in parenthesis is do to chain rule

Comment: The equality is wrong. Take $f(x)=\exp(x)-1$. (I'm referring to the equality $f'(x)=...$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\forall n, \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{n}\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{\frac{x}{n}}=\frac{1}{n}f^{'}(0)$ by definition of differentiability. Then sum over all $n$, you will get the result.